Error in this code. I know this can be solved with a "named lifetime parameter", but I wanna know why exactly this specific code throws error at all?
fn main() {
    let strings = vec![String::from("hello")];
    let default = String::from("default");
    let s = first_or(&strings, &default);
    println!("{}", s);
}

fn first_or(strings: &Vec<String>, default: &String) -> &String {
    if strings.len() > 0 {
        &strings[0]
    } else {
        default
    }
}


I tried to just either return &strings[0] or default, but the error persisted. I dont want to know how to solve this error, but what specific part of this code is causing it and why?

Because the compiler doesn't know if the return type borrows from strings or from default or from both or from neither, that's why.

It's very plain, none of the elision rules apply, so the lifetimes can't be elided.

This is almost literally a textbook example in the book: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#lifetime-annotations-in-function-signatures

In Rust, all references have lifetimes. It would be annoying if you always had to write those lifetimes out, so the compiler can often figure out what you want. This is called lifetime elison.
// Notice how you don't have to write out the lifetimes.
fn elided(s: &str) -> &str {
    s
}

// This function does the exact same thing, but the lifetimes are spelled out explicitly.
fn explicit<'a>(s: &'a str) -> &'a str {
    s
}

In your example, however, the compiler is unable to do this. For all the compiler knows, strings and default might have different lifetimes. In order to write your function you need to spell out the lifetimes explicitly.
// note that `strings` and `default` both have the same lifetime as the output
fn first_or<'a>(strings: &'a Vec<String>, default: &'a String) -> &'a String {
    if strings.len() > 0 {
        &strings[0]
    } else {
        default
    }
}

For a more detailed explanation, see the Rust book's section on lifetime elison.
